# How to get only the reference ws name from a cell formula

Tags: vb.net, vba

Does anyone know how to get the following string from this sample cell formula for example:

Formula:
=main!A1:A10

Wanted string:
main

I want to do this using VB.net or VBA. What are the possible ways that I can do this? Should I just  use string functions for this and apply conditions that will make it get the wanted output? Or are there functions in excel interop in vb.net that will let me do this?

I just need some small code snippets for this. I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this i think it will work :

```
dim SheetName as string
SheetName = mid(YourSheet.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1.split("!")(0),2)
if InStr(SheetName, "(") <0 then
    SheetName = split(SheetName,"(")(1)
end if
```

I hope this change will fulfill your quest.

Comment: Thank you. If my formula is =SUM(main!A1:A10) it doesn't get ofcourse the main only. It includes the SUM( string.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, assuming A1 contains your formula.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Excel.Range("$A$1")    
    Debug.Print rng.Precedents.Worksheet.Name    
End Sub
```

`Precedents` gives you the `Range` on which the cell depends. This may or may not be contiguous. The `Range` object has a `Worksheet` property (think of it as the `Range`'s parent), and `Name` returns the name of that worksheet.

Elegantly, this does not rely on any string parsing. You'll need to enhance this if the formula depends on more than one worksheet, but this will get you started.

Comment: This should be a good start for me, will research on this function. Thank you.